# Python Py2exe - Compiling a folder into the executable

Tags: python, py2exe

I've tried to compile my python script into a single executable using Py2exe.  I can get everything into the executable except for the data files which sit outside the executable.  And I have to include every file that's inside my data files folder separately.

Question one: 
How do I compile a single folder, with all the files inside without having to name each file individually?

Question two:
How do I compile this folder into the executable using Py2exe?